# FB Login Button Not Showing in Chrome and IE

Tags: php, facebook, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have seen similar problems posted here, and I have added as many solutions that made sense (HTML Doc changes, relocating and reordering the scripts/button) but the button only renders and is click-able in Firefox.

Facebook Tab/Page interface is here: facebook.com/TodaysAesthetics/app_157293451075619

Hosted Page can be seen by clicking the link... (I can't post more links)

FB Settings:
App Domains: hosted site WITH and WITHOUT www (I read www could be a culprit)
Website with Facebook Login->Site URL: DOMAIN/facebook/
(I have tried DOMAIN/facebook/ and DOMAIN/facebook/todays)

Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
          define('YOUR_APP_ID', '[edit]');
          define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', '[edit]');
          function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) {
          $args = array();
          list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], 2);
          $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
          $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
          if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
             return null;
          }
          $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload,
          $application_secret, $raw = true);
          if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
              return null;
          }
          $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
         . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&client_secret=" . $application_secret.     "&redirect_uri=" . "&code=" . $data['code'];
          $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
          $params = null;
          parse_str($response, $args);
          return $args;
        }
          $cookie = get_facebook_cookie(YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET);
          if ($cookie) {
               $user = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com    /me?access_token=' . $cookie['access_token']));
        }
    ?>
          <?php if ($cookie) { ?>
 <form>
              <input type="button" id="hide" value="Print" onClick="printc()">
            </form>
          [MY COUPON IMAGE]
            <?php } else { ?>
            <fb:login-button scope="email,user_birthday,user_location" onlogin="window.location.reload()" autologoutlink="true">Connect to Facebook to View Special</fb:login-button>
                      <?php } ?>
                <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
            <script>
              FB.init({appId: '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>', status: true,
                       cookie: true, xfbml: true,oauth:true});
              FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
              });
            </script>
```

Please let me know if I can provide any other information, or if I missed any answers.  I HAVE tried to change the order of these scripts vs. div, etc, but I will try anything at this point. THANKS

Comment: Can you indent your code please ?

Comment: Please let me know if I did it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have embedded the JS SDK using HTTP – and so Chrome and IE block it from being executed when the page is requested via HTTPS. *(This is, btw., something you could have easily spotted yourself, if you had just looked into the error console of these browsers – so please familiarize yourself with this kind of debug tools and use them in the future!)*

Instead of

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

use

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

– this let’s the browser chose the right protocol itself.

Comment: Thanks, I do see this in the error console:
[blocked] The page at https://www.webopenings.com/facebook/todays/ ran insecure content from http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js.

But it didn't really mean anything to me. I never knew that leaving off the http/https option would give the browser the option to chose. Thank you, simple and informative.